# Unable to create mysql database using flask sqlalchemy, Operational Error in SQL

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pymysql

Using Flask, I'm attempting to build a web application for user authentication, however the database is not being created and I keep receiving `sql.errors.opertionalerror`.
When I use sqlite, it functions perfectly, but when I use mysql, I receive the above mentioned error.
I am providing the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost:3306/db_name'` in the enivronment file.
Is it acceptable to use the Python MySQL `(pymysql)` connector to establish a database?

```
import pymysql as pm

def creating_user_db():
    try:
        mydb = pm.connect(host='localhost',
                            user='username',
                            passwd='password'
                        )
        mydb.autocommit = False
        cursor = mydb.cursor()

        mydb.cursor().execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_name;')


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        mydb.close()
```

Please correct me where I made a mistake and assist me with this.
Thanks In advance!

Comment: What does the error actually say?

Comment: Hi @Peter, sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database 'db_name'") this is the error I'm getting.